# Drop rows if value in column changes

Tags: python, pandas

Assume I have the following pandas data frame:

```
   my_class  value
0      1      1
1      1      2
2      1      3
3      2      4
4      2      5
5      2      6
6      2      7
7      2      8
8      2      9
9      3     10
10     3     11
11     3     12
```

I want to identify the indices of "my_class" where the class changes and remove n rows after and before this index. The output of this example (with n=2) should look like:

```
   my_class  value
0      1      1
5      2      6
6      2      7
11     3     12
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I can use a for-loop and loop through the column to find the changes and remove the rows, but I want to avoid for-loops since my data set is much larger than this example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach:

```
# where class changes happen
s = df['my_class'].ne(df['my_class'].shift(-1).fillna(df['my_class']))

# mask with `bfill` and `ffill`
df[~(s.where(s).bfill(limit=1).ffill(limit=2).eq(1))]
```

Output:

```
    my_class  value
0          1      1
5          2      6
6          2      7
11         3     12
```

Answer (score 1):

```
my_class = np.array([1] * 3 + [2] * 6 + [3] * 3)
cols = np.c_[my_class, np.arange(len(my_class)) + 1]

df = pd.DataFrame(cols, columns=['my_class', 'value'])
df['diff'] = df['my_class'].diff().fillna(0)

idx2drop = []

for i in df[df['diff'] == 1].index:
    idx2drop += range(i - 2, i + 2)

print(df.drop(idx_drop)[['my_class', 'value']])
```

Output:

```
      my_class  value
  0        1      1
  5        2      6
  6        2      7
  11       3     12
```

Answer (score 0):

One of possible solutions is to:

- Make use of the fact that the index contains consecutive integers.
- Find index values where *class* changes.
- For each such index generate a sequence of indices from *n-2*
  to *n+1* and concatenate them.
- Retrieve rows with indices not in this list.

The code to do it is:

```
ind = df[df['my_class'].diff().fillna(0, downcast='infer') == 1].index
df[~df.index.isin([item for sublist in
    [ range(i-2, i+2) for i in ind ] for item in sublist])]
```